# Neo4j CSV Import: Remove/Filter specific values during import

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I import data via CSV upload with py2neo. The following script reads each column and it's rows of the file and push to Neo4j. File includes thousands of rows under four columns. Some columns includes values like "n/a", "undefined", "null", "unknown" and blank cells. When the script iterates the columns and rows, It pushes all data also to the db.

I want, when the script reads "n/a" or "undefined", "null"... it should ignore these data and doesn't push the db.

```
result_data = "./Excel2CSV/result.csv"
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (result:RESULT) ASSERT result.id IS UNIQUE")
with open(result_data, 'r+') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)
    batch = graph.cypher.begin()
    try:
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        for row in reader:
            if row:
                f_name = strip(row[0])
                l_name = strip(row[1])
                nickname = strip(row[2]
                text = strip(row[3])
                result = strip(row[4])
                query = """
                    merge (person:Person {f_name:{a}, l_name{b}, nickname{c}})
                    merge (text:TEXT {value:{d}})
                    merge (Result:RESULT {value:{e}})
                    merge (person)-[:WROTE]->(text)
                    merge (person)-[:REPLIED]->(result)
                """
                batch.append(query, {"a": f_name, "b": l_name, "c": nickname, "d": text, "e": result})
                i += 1
                j += 1
            batch.process()
```

### **EDIT REGARDING THE BELOW ANSWER:**

For example I am creating a node called "person" and this node has 3 properties "f_name" coming from {a} column, "l_name" coming from {b} column and "nickname" come from {c} column. Assume each of the columns have the above "unwanted" values. I created the node with the first "f_name" property:

```
WITH CASE WHEN {a} IN ["n/a", "undefined", "null"] THEN "" ELSE {a} END AS x
OPTIONAL MATCH (person:Person { f_name: x })
```

and before passing to

`WITH CASE WHEN text IS NULL THEN [x] ELSE [] END AS todo
FOREACH (i IN todo | CREATE (person:Person { l_name: i })),`

I need to apply same filtering to remove unwanted values for "l_name" and "nickname" properties. And I think I should define the new properties to append the new properties to "person" node.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix your last query so that it would "work". However, the approach would still be flawed, as the DB could end up with multiple `:TEXT` nodes having no properties. This is because every `MERGE` with a "bad" property would fail to match an existing node and create a new new node with that property, and then delete the property (because you set its value to `null`) -- probably not what you intended.

So, I propose that you pick a non-null value (for example, "", or even the string "null") to set the value to if the incoming `{c}` has a "bad" value.

## To match nodes having a single property

Using the above proposal, the following simple query should work (replacing "bad" values with "") if nodes only have a single property:

```
WITH CASE WHEN {c} IN ["n/a", "undefined", "null"] THEN "" ELSE {c} END AS x
MERGE (text:TEXT { value: x });
```

Not only does this do what you probably intended, but it is also more efficient, since it requires no additional `WHERE` OR `SET` clauses.

## To match nodes that may have "extra" properties

Since a `MERGE` clause (that specifies any properties) only matches nodes whose *complete* property set matches the clause, the above single-property solution will not work if you want to find a match *even if* a node has additional properties not specified in the `MERGE` clause.

Here is a query that should work if "extra" properties should be allowed.

```
WITH CASE WHEN {c} IN ["n/a", "undefined", "null"] THEN "" ELSE {c} END AS x
OPTIONAL MATCH (text:TEXT { value: x })
WITH CASE WHEN text IS NULL THEN [x] ELSE [] END AS todo
FOREACH (i IN todo | CREATE (text:TEXT { value: i }));
```

`OPTIONAL MATCH` is not as picky as `MERGE`, and will succeed even if there are "extra" properties. If `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails, it assigns `null` to its node and relationship identifiers. `FOREACH` does nothing if the collection it iterates over is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution worked well for the nodes which has only 1 property like `text.value` . However, while my app goes bigger, I will have some other nodes which have more than 1 property. For example: `MERGE (person:PERSON {f_name{a}, l_name{b}})` In your solution, you assign a new single "x" value. How it can be modified for the node which has multiple properties? Thanks

Comment: To answer the specific question in your previous comment: you can add more `CASE ... AS ...` subclauses to the top `WITH` clause, separated by commas. Then, in your `MERGE` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause, you just need to add the additional properties.

Comment: Appreciates for your explanation and code. I think I should have specified that the extra properties coming from other columns which need to be cleaned from unwanted values. I tried your edited reply and different possibilities but it gave me errors. I edited my question to make it more clear. Sorry for coming with new questions.. Thanks for your help up to now.